# How to create sub menus (folders) under Administration menu in SAP Business One studio 9.2 using C# code

Tags: c#, add-on, sapb1

I'm very new to SAP Business one studio, I want to create sub menus (folders) under the Administration menu in SAP Business One Studio like:

Administration --> Add-Ons --> My Addon example

Answer (score 0):

you can add new menus under the Module menu by using the following code...

```
SAPbouiCOM.Menus oMenus = null;
SAPbouiCOM.MenuItem oMenuItem = null;

//**********************************************************

oMenus = SBO_Application.Menus;
SAPbouiCOM.MenuCreationParams oCreationPackage = null;

//**********************************************************
//Creating a new menu item after the menu whose UID is
//"3328"
//**********************************************************
oCreationPackage = ( ( SAPbouiCOM.MenuCreationParams )( SBO_Application.CreateObject( SAPbouiCOM.BoCreatableObjectType.cot_MenuCreationParams ) ) );

oMenuItem = SBO_Application.Menus.Item( "3328" );

try{
//**********************************************************
//Adding the new menu to the main menu
//**********************************************************

    oMenus.AddEx( oCreationPackage );
    oMenuItem = SBO_Application.Menus.Item( "3328" );

//**********************************************************
//Adding the sub menu of string type to the newly added menu
//**********************************************************

    oMenus = oMenuItem.SubMenus;
    oCreationPackage.Type = SAPbouiCOM.BoMenuType.mt_STRING;
    oCreationPackage.UniqueID = "routesheet";
    oCreationPackage.String = "RouteSheet";

    oMenus.AddEx( oCreationPackage );

}
```

This is an example where I am adding a new menu named Route Sheet under the Module menu whose UID is 43520.

Hope it work.